# MySQL optimize variables for large tables

Tags: mysql, optimization

I need help in setting all of the MySQL Variables and any recommendations that anyone may have.

We currently have 1 server:

- 4 x Dual Core 2.4 GHz
- 32GB RAM
- Windows Server 2008 Web Edition

MySQL is setup as:

- 1 Master Server (Port 3301)
- 4 Slaves (Ports 3302, 3303, 3304, 3305)

Replication is working a treat. The idea of the slaves is to handle many connections

MySQL config files look like this:

```
[mysqld]  
datadir="E:\MySQL_Rep\data_3302"  
init-file="E:\MySQL_Rep\mysql-init-slave.txt"  
port=3302  
server-id=3302  
default-storage-engine=myisam  
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 512M  
join_buffer_size = 5M  
query_cache_limit = 1M  
max_connections=1510  
tmp_table_size = 18M  
skip-innodb  
low-priority-updates  
delay-key-write=ALL  
innodb_write_io_threads = 5  
innodb_read_io_threads = 10  
skip-ssl  
slave_compressed_protocol  
slave-skip-errors=all  
sync_binlog = 1  
join_buffer_size = 20M  
replicate-wild-ignore-table=db.search_result%  
key_buffer_size=4G  
expire_logs_days=1    
relay-log-space-limit=10G  
myisam-recover=backup,force  
read_rnd_buffer_size=1G  
read_buffer_size=1G
```

The above is identical for each of the 4 slaves, only changing "3302" to 3303, 3304 and 3305.

We have 3 main tables:

```
Name: keyword_index  
Engine: MyISAM  
Rows: 1,521,140  
Avg Row Length: 25  
Data Length: 38150952  
Index Length: 48757760  
Columns: id(INT 11), word(VARCHAR 45, UNIQUE)  

Name: keyword_prodid  
Engine: MyISAM  
Rows: 42,611,210  
Avg Row Length: 17  
Data Length: 724390570  
Index Length: 1796547584  
Columns: id_kw(BIGINT 20, INDEXED), id_prod(BIGINT 20)  

Name: products  
Engine: MyISAM  
Rows: 7,192,937  
Avg Row Length: 1018  
Data Length: 7544910024  
Index Length: 686807040  
Columns: prod_id(BIGINT 20),... ... ...
```

Queries I Run:

```
SELECT kwi.id FROM keyword_index kwi WHERE kwi.`word` = 'mobile' LIMIT 1
```

EXPLAIN:

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'kwi', 'const', 'word_UNIQUE', 'word_UNIQUE', '137', 'const', '1', ''`
```

This runs in apparently less than 0 seconds, and returns `5531`;

---

Using the above results

```
SELECT 
    id_prod,count(*) AS count,
    @sID 
FROM keyword_prodid kwp 
WHERE kwp.id_kw = 264012 
    OR kwp.id_kw = 817869 
    OR kwp.id_kw = 5531 
    OR kwp.id_kw = 7167 
    OR kwp.id_kw = 3462 
    OR kwp.id_kw = 811564 
GROUP BY id_prod 
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10 INTO OUTFILE 'THEFILE'
```

EXPLAIN:

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'kwp', 'range', 'PRIMARY,id_kw', 'PRIMARY', '8', NULL, '55071', 'Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort'`
```

This runs in **30 to 60 seconds**, which is where I'm having my problem. The query returns a list of product IDs with the products that have the most keywords coming out first in the list.

I then use the list that is generated from above to get the products with the above IDs out of the products table.

My question is, is there a way of getting this query to run faster, by either optimizing the query or by tweaking the config file settings. All of the settings are pretty much guessed, and at this stage we are only able to run this on 1 physical server.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Show create table for `keyword_prodid`. PS: if you need that often - you may be better have the aggregated data precalculated somewhere

Comment: Create statement for keyword_prodid:  
CREATE TABLE `keyword_prodid` (
  `id_kw` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_prod` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_kw`,`id_prod`),
  KEY `id_kw` (`id_kw`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

Comment: What if you create composite `id_kw + id_prod`?

Comment: @zerkms - is that not the same as the PRIMARY KEY index? as both columns are primary keys to prevent duplicates?

Comment: nope, composite index is not the same as 2 separated ones. Composite index contains the data from both columns

Comment: @zerkms - thank you, I will give that a try tomorrow and let you know how it goes

Comment: @zerkms - Wow! Thank you - what a massive improvement, cannot thank you enough. - Please add the composite index as an answer

Comment: don't forget to drop original `id_kw` index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create composite index `id_kw + id_prod`.

**Important**: as long as `id_kw + id_prod` index contains `id_kw` in its left part - you don't need a single `id_kw` index anymore, so drop it.

Also this

```
kwp.id_kw = 264012 
OR kwp.id_kw = 817869 
OR kwp.id_kw = 5531 
OR kwp.id_kw = 7167 
OR kwp.id_kw = 3462 
OR kwp.id_kw = 811564
```

can be written as `id_kw IN (264012, 817869, ...)`